# get form submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have index file where I load and show form. now I can not get values to other file where I process receivied values.
like this i get event fired but i dont get any value when i debug saveEdit.php file

HTML:

```
form name="formDetail" method="post" action="#" >
    <table id="edittable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Nimi:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="nimi" name="nimi" placeholder="Kappaleen nimi" type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Levy:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="levy" name="levy" placeholder="Levyn tunnus" type="text" width="10px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Artisti:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="artisti" name="artisti" placeholder="Kappaleen esittäjä" type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Kieli:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="kieli" name="kieli" placeholder="Alkuperäiskieli" type="text" width="20">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Numero:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="numero" name="numeron" placeholder="Numero" type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="submit" class='save_button' type="button" value="Tallenna" />
                    <input name="delete" type="button" value="Poista" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_number" id="id_number"   />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.clickable-row', function () {
        $('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var selectedRow = $(this);
        var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
        console.log(td);

        $('#nimi').val(td[0].innerText);
        $('#artisti').val(td[1].innerText);
        $('#levy').val(td[2].innerText);
        $('#kieli').val(td[3].innerText);
        $('#numero').val(td[4].innerText);
        $('#id_number').val(td[4].innerText);

        console.log("test");
        $('#edit').show();
    });


    $('#formDetail').on('click', '.save_button', function () {
        $.post("saveEdit.php", $(this).serialize())
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
    });

    $('#pageContent').load('container.php');
});
```

Comment: Add the form code

Comment: If I try use $('#formDetail').submit(function(){...
} nothing happend

Comment: `#formDetail` is button's id or form's?

Comment: please provide clear need

Answer (score 0):

Try using a submit handler with a `preventDefault()` which stops the standard submit POST from processing :

```
$('#formDetail').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("saveEdit.php", $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, now I dont understand what you mean $('#formEditeditBiisi').serialize() ..... you mean  $('#formDetail').serialize() ,right? but what I do next??

Comment: As others have said, provide your html and maybe we can be of more help.

Comment: I try, page say that there is too much code :)  I try again

Answer (score 0):

Stay with the delegated submit listener since it appears you are loading the content using ajax.

But you also need to prevent the default browser form submit process:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formEditeditBiisi', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();//prevent browser submitting form
  $.post("saveEdit.php", $(this).serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
});
```

Comment: No effect. when I debug file it newer fired when I click button

Comment: Don't see any ID to match `#formEditeditBiisi` in your html

Comment: then where did that ID come from in the original question? Use whatever ID your form has